How to enable ext-sodium on a PHP 8.2 docker image that was not built with `--with-sodium`?
I'm trying to use a GitLab CI PHP docker image (PHP: 8.2) and I need to enable the sodium extension.
It seems that sodium has been incorporated into PHP, so normally PHP needs to be built with the --with-sodium flag for it to be used.
However, this is a CI environment and I can only modify the Docker image; I can't use a different one.  I'm using the docker image drupalci/php-8.2-apache.
In .gitlab-ci.yml, I tried this:
before_script:
 - apt-get update 
 - apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libsodium-dev

libsodium gets installed but the sodium extension is not enabled for PHP.
How can I do that?

I'm not sure how you think you can reasonably solve this issue? If PHP wasn't compiled with support for something, you can't enable it, despite what the GPT trash below might say.

before_script:
  - apt-get update 
  - apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libsodium-dev
  - docker-php-ext-enable sodium || echo "Sodium extension not found"
  - php -m | grep sodium || echo "Sodium extension is not enabled"

or if docker-php-ext does not work try this:
before_script:
  - apt-get update 
  - apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libsodium-dev
  - echo "extension=sodium.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/sodium.ini
  - php -m | grep sodium || echo "Sodium extension is not enabled"


For docker-php-ext-enable sodium, I get error: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/sodium does not exist, and for echo "extension=sodium.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/sodium.ini, I get PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sodium.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20220829/sodium.so.

Add to apt-get install

apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libsodium-dev libapache2-mod-php8.2 php8.2-dev gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config

If this fail, try to compile sodium

mkdir -p /usr/src/php/ext/sodium
curl -fsSL https://github.com/php/php-src/archive/php-8.2.0.tar.gz | tar xz --strip-components=1 -C /usr/src/php/ext/sodium
docker-php-ext-install sodium

